# Mapping one range into another in an exponential but computationally cheap fashion

Tags: continuity, linear-transformations

I have a continuous variable x whose range is within [0, r], and a target range of [0, u]. I can linearly transform one range into the other by doing `x/r * u`, but I would like to do this in an exponential fashion (where bigger values of the first range map to bigger and bigger values of the second. I can have, arbitrarily, `(x/r)^3` * u. However, is this the best solution? Especially considering that calculating `(x/r)^3` is not computationally cheap.